# query to Prepare a function to which user will pass a date and will return the day of that date using ORACLE

Tags: sql, oracle, date

query to Prepare a function to which user will pass a date and will return the day of that date using ORACLE..

Suppose i will put 10th december 2016 and the result will come is Saturday... like this only.

Comment: Have you tried something yet?

Comment: Why don't you simply use `to_char()`?

Comment: Guys, please stop bullying newbies

Comment: well said @DuduMarkovitz

Comment: This question seems about homework. From [help/on-topic]:"Questions asking for homework help must include a summary of the work you've done so far to solve the problem, and a description of the difficulty you are having solving it". So this question is against SO rules and shoud be closed. And I believe it's incredible that peolpe upvoted it

Comment: Which is fine, but why down-voting the post and closing it within a minute?

Comment: P.s. you're guessing it is homework. Might be, but maybe it is a young developer working with databases for the first time? Or maybe it is a high school teenager trying to write her first application?

Comment: @DuduMarkovitz - How I thought: the question is not clear (does OP need a function or a plain SQL? which format/type for the output? does the OP need only the day, or cut off hours, keeping month/year ?) so I voted to close; people can disagree with me and keep the question open, but I believe it's really poor and shows no effort, so I downvoted. It seems ( I'm not sure of course) an homework question, so I added a comment to make the OP notice that there are rules to observe. For all these reasons, upvoting ("This question shows research effort; it is useful and clear") is incredible to me.

Comment: @Aleksej - Indeed, this question is not clear, but we can ask for clarifications and wait for the OP to response (and the emphasis here is on **wait** :-))

Answer (score 2):

replace **sysdate** with a date parameter
(e.g. **:dt**)

```
select to_char(sysdate,'Day') from dual;
```

Wednesday

Comment: not todays date,i will enter any date and the name of the day will come.

Comment: Kind reminder to approve the answer